# How to import NgxDatetimeRangePickerModule not to root module?

Tags: angular

I've decided to use NgxDatetimeRangePickerModule (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-datetime-range-picker)
Acording to instrucxtions i should import it forRoot in app.module, but in this case i can't use component from this module in child modules. If i import NgxDatetimeRangePickerModule in child module (where i need to use shared component) i get error 'BrowserModule has already been loaded.'.
It looks like this module import BrowserModule in it, but it gives me no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Anything imported in your AppModule can be used by children modules…

Comment: I know it, i just say that case described in instruction doesn't fit me

Comment: In what way does it "not fit you"?

Comment: i need to use component from NgxDatetimeRangePickerModule not in root module

Comment: Are you using version 1.1.3? https://github.com/BhavinPatel04/ngx-datetime-range-picker/issues/4

Comment: yep, i a'm using 1.1.5 version, but i tried 1.1.3 and got same problem